# Flatten an array of objects that may contain arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<object>` which may or may not contain some nested collections. For example, my starting point might look something like this:

```
[ "foo", 2, [1, 2, 3, 4], "bar" ]
```

And I want to flatten it to:

```
[ "foo", 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, "bar" ]
```

I'm thinking a `SelectMany` should work here but can't quite find the right combination. I could brute force it, but I thought there should be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blog.mijalko.com/2009/12/flatten-array-of-arrays-using-linq.html

Comment: @MikeCheel: Actually I did, but that's not quite the same thing. That's an list of lists. This is a list of objects, some of which might be lists. I want to select both the objects that aren't lists and the contents of each list.

Comment: Is your nesting always 2 levels deep or you can have even more deeply nested arrays?

Comment: @MikeCheel: That is not relevant.

Comment: @nemesv: It's just the 2 levels at the moment. I don't anticipate it being any deeper (or if it is, I'll really have to rethink the whole thing!)

Comment: What kind of list-type objects can be in your list? I ask because `"foo"` is a `string`, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, and it sounds like you don't want `['f', 'o', 'o', ...]`.

Comment: @JoelRondeau: A very good question - no, I don't want to split strings into individual members, that would be very bad. The types in the list will likely be `int`, `double`, `string` and arrays (or lists) of said types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<object> source = new object[] { "test", 1, new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, "test" };

var result = source .SelectMany(x => x is Array ? ((IEnumerable)x).Cast<object>() : Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1));
```

To get it work with nested arrays make the lambda recursive:

```
IEnumerable<object> source = new object[] { "test", 1, new object[] { 1, 2, new [] { "nested", "nested2" } }, "test" };

Func<IEnumerable<object>, IEnumerable<object>> flatten = null;
flatten = s => s.SelectMany(x => x is Array ? flatten(((IEnumerable)x).Cast<object>()) : Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1));

var result = flatten(source);
```

Comment: That won't handle nested arrays.

Comment: @SLaks I've updated my answer with recursive solution.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter recursive alternative:

```
IEnumerable<object> source = new object[] { "test", 1, new object[] { 1, 2, new [] { "nested", "nested2" } }, "test" };

Func<IEnumerable<object>, IEnumerable<object>> flatten = null;
flatten = s => s == null ? null : s.SelectMany(x => 
   flatten(x as IEnumerable<object>) ?? new [] { x }
);
var result = flatten(source);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit nasty, but works.. assuming only one level:

```
a.SelectMany(t => 
     (t is IEnumerable<object>)
      ? (IEnumerable<object>)t 
      : new object[] {t})
```

I suspect the most "elegant" solution is really to write an extension.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this) {
    foreach (var item in @this) {
        if (item is IEnumerable<T>) {
            foreach (var subitem in Flatten((IEnumerable<T>)item)) {
                yield return subitem;
            }
        }
        else yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's clever! I still prefer mine for clarity though.

Comment: Yes; beyond a certain point, brevity and clarity can be mutually exclusive.