# flattening json structure with arrays to multiple flat objects without arrays

Tags: c#, json, recursion, json.net

I'm not sure whether did I describe the problem in subject 100% correctly, but I believe that the examples will do the trick.

I have JSON structure like below (note: there is small chance that this might change, so i need to lean forward to generic solution)

*One invoice with multiple line items*:

```
{
    "contactName": "Company",
    "lineItems": [
     {
        "quantity": 7.0,
        "description": "Beer No* 45.5 DIN KEG"
     },
     {
        "quantity": 2.0,
        "description": "Beer Old 49.5 DIN KEG"
     }
     ],
    "invoiceNumber": "C6188372"
}
```

And this is the wanted result data structure (*multiple invoices with duplicated data and different line item info*):

```
[{
    "contactName": "Company",
    "quantity": 7.0,
    "description": "Beer No* 45.5 DIN KEG"
    "invoiceNumber": "C6188372"
},{
    "contactName": "Company",
    "quantity": 2.0,
    "description": "Beer Old 49.5 DIN KEG"
    "invoiceNumber": "C6188372"
}]
```

So each "line item" from "invoice" should "result" in new invoice with duplicated other elements.

Small variations around result data structure are accepted, i can adjust my code around it. 
I've been spinning around using several similar questions such as:

- [C# flattening json structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394551/c-sharp-flattening-json-structure/35838986)
- [Flatten an array of objects that may contain arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562326/flatten-an-array-of-objects-that-may-contain-arrays)
- [How can I flatten a collection of objects (which in turn contain collections)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439829/how-can-i-flatten-a-collection-of-objects-which-in-turn-contain-collections)
- [Generically Flatten Json using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782937/generically-flatten-json-using-c-sharp) (etc). i believe that this is the closest solution? but unsure if there is some better approach

For more background, i need this for CSV export. So result set should be two rows in generated CSV.

Any hints/tips are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify are you consuming the first JSON structure and wanting to restructure it to the second structure? or are your C# Classes generating the first JSON structure and you instead want it to generate the second JSON structure (Effectively the first JSON structure should never exist)

Comment: @Skintkingle First is correct - I'm consuming 1st JSON structure and i need to restructure it to 2nd structure.

Comment: Do you have a C# Class at the moment that deserializes nicely from the first example? if so could you supply that Class in the question. :)

Comment: @Skintkingle I'm working with object/JObject/JToken etc due to dynamic data structure, so (sadly) I do not have fixed c# class

Comment: So the JSON you are reading in has an unknown data structure? or it just conditionally sometimes doesn't supply a parameter here or there?

Comment: In general, JSON that I'm receiving has unknown data structure (it is defined by external source using Json Schema, but that is another story)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a function like this:

```
//Pass in the name of the array property you want to flatten
public string FlattenJson(string input, string arrayProperty)
{
    //Convert it to a JObject
    var unflattened = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(input);

    //Return a new array of items made up of the inner properties
    //of the array and the outer properties
    var flattened = ((JArray)unflattened[arrayProperty])
        .Select(item => new JObject(
            unflattened.Properties().Where(p => p.Name != arrayProperty), 
            ((JObject)item).Properties()));

    //Convert it back to Json
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flattened);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var flattenedJson = FlattenJson(inputJson, "lineItems");
```

Comment: I have tried this, and i think that this will do the trick. 

I will need to expand it to be recursive and to detect which properties are arrays so that I do not need to explicitly write "lineItems" in code.

Anyhow, I have accepted your answer as it gave me idea how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom `JsonConverter` if you are able to Deserialize/Serialize into a strongly typed class.
Invoice information I would imagine should be in some semi-structured object so this should be doable:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public List<Item> LineItems { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And then with the JsonConverter you can flatten it based upon the Items (Or any other property/properties you may want)

```
public class InvoiceFlattener : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = value as Invoice;
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (var item in obj.LineItems)
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(obj.ContactName));
            writer.WriteValue(obj.ContactName);
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(item.Quantity));
            writer.WriteValue(item.Quantity);
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(item.Description));
            writer.WriteValue(item.Description);
            writer.WritePropertyName(nameof(obj.InvoiceNumber));
            writer.WriteValue(obj.InvoiceNumber);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Invoice);
    }
}
```

And to use this Converter you supply it when Serializing

```
        var invoice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Invoice>(inputJson);
        var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(invoice, new InvoiceFlattener());
```

As you have probably worked out this converter doesn't work when deserializing but if this is a requirement you can write the logic in the ReadJson converter method.
The downside to this is you will be required to maintain the converter should the structure of the `Invoice` class ever change. But it keeps us in a strongly typed world

Comment: unfortunately, i do not live in strongly typed world in this scenario - input data structure is "dictated" by external Json Schema which can be modified at any given time, and i need to adapt to it :(

Comment: In that case I hope the property that contains your list of lineItems doesn't change! DavidGs answer is probably what you want then.

Comment: I just wrote a comment below his answer: I will expand his answer to be bit more generic, (to detect arrays) so that i do not need to hardcode "lineItems" string in the code. Thanks for your assistance though.

Answer (score 2):

With external lib [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library, you can convert your JSON to expected CSV format with few lines of code

```
string json = @"{
    ""contactName"": ""Company"",
    ""lineItems"": [
     {
        ""quantity"": 7.0,
        ""description"": ""Beer No* 45.5 DIN KEG""
     },
     {
        ""quantity"": 2.0,
        ""description"": ""Beer Old 49.5 DIN KEG""
     }
     ],
    ""invoiceNumber"": ""C6188372""
}";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var p = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json))
{
    using (var w = new ChoCSVWriter(sb)
        .WithFirstLineHeader()
        )
        w.Write(p
            .SelectMany(r1 => ((dynamic[])r1.lineItems).Select(r2 => new
            {
                r1.contactName,
                r2.quantity,
                r2.description,
                r1.invoiceNumber
            })));
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

**Output CSV:**

```
contactName,quantity,description,invoiceNumber
Company,7,Beer No* 45.5 DIN KEG,C6188372
Company,2,Beer Old 49.5 DIN KEG,C6188372
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In meantime, I've done what I needed using DavidGs answer, however thanks for info! I was not aware of this library. I'll check it out.